# Twig: reset variable from parent

Tags: twig

let say I have a layout/parent/child twig, I wanted to do something it is not the same from the child by setting the variable.

layout.html.twig:

```
{% block content %}
    {% if showRed is defined and showRed == true %}
        <div>Red</div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

parent.html.twig:

```
{% extends './layout.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
    {% set showRed = true %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

child.html.twig:

```
{% extends './parent.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
        {% set showRed = false %}
        {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

Is there a best practice for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible but you would only need to define the default state to `true` when the variable is not already set in `parent.html.twig`

```
{% extends 'layout.twig' %}
{% block content %}
    {% if not showRed is defined %}
        {% set showRed = true %}
    {% endif %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/ftxhr6)

---

However this approach feels off to me, a "better" solution in my opinion would be to create an extra block `red` and overwrite that one

layout.twig

```
{% block content %}
    Default content
    {% block red %}
    Red
    {% endblock red %}
{% endblock %}
```

parent.twig

```
{% extends 'layout.twig' %}
```

child.twig

```
{% extends 'parent.twig' %}

{% block red %}
{% endblock %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/ftxhr6/2)

Comment: 100% what I needed!